# Formatting the current date

Tags: vb.net, excel, date-formatting, vba

Either I just can't seem to find the right way to word the problem or it's a lot more complicated than I thought, but what is the easiest way to assign the current date to a variable and format it to a specific format? Basically, I want to do the VB.net equivalent of *this* VBA line:

```
formatted_date = Format(Date, "yyyy-m-d")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim formattedDate as String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d")
```

Note that capital M is for month, lowercase m would get you minutes.

Comment: Ah HA! So, fun fact, the code that I have now is actually doing exactly what I wanted it to, I just didn't know about the capitol M vs. lowercase m issue. Yours also worked great. Thanks John!

Answer (score 1):

If by "Date" you really mean current date (and not an example variable), the VB.NET Equivalent is "Today"

Do one of these things... (whichever you like):

```
formatted_date = Today.ToString("yyyy-M-d")

formatted_date = String.Format("{0:yyyy-M-d}", Today)
```

If your "Date" was just an example variable, just replace "Today" in the above examples with your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

to simply : `SomeDate.ToString("yyyy-m-d")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim format As String = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format))
```