# Date of first day of current month

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have a script recorded from SAP ERP via SAP GUI, to run transaction code `VA05`. I need to run this script each day (I am fine achieving this) and I need the start date to always be the first date of the current month.

My script is below. What should I put in the VB script to replace "01.03.2021" so I always get the first date in the current month please?

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "va05"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBCOM-AUDAT").text = "01.03.2021"       '<=== HERE
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBCOM-AUDAT").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBCOM-AUDAT").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Comment: There are in fact several questions here, which have already answers in Stack Overflow: how to [get the current date and how to format a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505408/formatting-the-current-date), how to extract text portions, how to concatenate date and texts...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your string "01.03.2021" with this:

```
Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

[Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function) function will give you date for actual day

[Year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function) function will extract year from date as integer

[Month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) function will extract month from date as integer

[DateSerial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) function will return Date to you based on arguments(year, month, day)

And finally [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function will format your date into desired format (dd.MM.yyyy) in your case.

So your code should look like this:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "va05"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBCOM-AUDAT").text = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), "dd.MM.yyyy")  
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBCOM-AUDAT").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBCOM-AUDAT").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Keep in mind that you can create a function for this (GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth) if you want to use it in more than one place. The function might look something like this:

```
Function GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth() As Date
    ' Lets say today is 18/03/2021 ( dd/MM/yyyy ) then
    ' variables y will be 2019 and variable m will be 3
    Dim y As Integer: y = year(Date)
    Dim m As Integer: m = month(Date)
    
    ' Variable firstDay is of type Date
    ' and its value is going to be 01/03/2021
    Dim firstDay As Date: firstDay = DateSerial(y, m, 1)
    
    GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth = firstDay
End Function
```